# for loop through a dictionary - python3

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am just trying to make sense of the piece of code below:

```
names = [{'name': alice}, {'name':bob}, {'name': david}]

with_comma= ', '.join(name['name'] for name in names[:-1])
```

What is `name['name']` there?  How does it extract names from the corresponding dictionaries?

Additionally, what I learned from textbooks is we are supposed to write what will happen after every iteration of for loop "AFTER" the `for name in names[:-1]`, and where is it?

I hope I have written clearly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to read a Python tutorial. That's one of the most basic things about dictionaries.

Comment: That's not a for loop, it's a generator.

Comment: We understand you are a beginner, and that's fine. We all start like that. But you must learn at least the very basics to post meaningful and useful questions here. There are lots of learning resources out there. This is intended to be an encyclopedia-like platform for common programming issues and errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break down the code in smaller parts and understand the smaller parts to understand the whole.

`names` is a list containing three dictionaries, each of the dictionaries only contains a single key `'name'` with a value. Those values are apparently defined in some other part of the code that we're not given, as these values appear to have been assigned to the variables `alice`, `bob` and `david`.

`names[:-1]` means 'all the elements of names, except the last', so it's effectively `[{'name': alice}, {'name': bob}]`.

`name for name in names[:-1]` is a generator, which yields the elements of `names[:-1]` one at a time. So, it yields `{'name': alice}` first and then `{'name': bob}`, and then it completes since there is nothing more to yield.

`name['name']` tries to index the variable `name` with the key `'name'`. When `name` has the value `{'name': alice}`, `name['name']` is whatever the value of `alice` was when the dictionary was defined.

The `.join()` method of a string takes an iterable as an argument and puts every element from the iterable together in a new string, with a copy of the original string stuck inbetween each element.

So, this piece of code:

```
alice = 'Alice'
bob = 'Bob'
david = 'Whatever'

names = [{'name': alice}, {'name': bob}, {'name': david}]

with_comma= ', '.join(name['name'] for name in names[:-1])
```

Results in `with_comma` having the value `'Alice, Bob'`.

If this is code from a Python training though, I would recommend taking another class or course, because it's not doing a very good job of teaching you Python, throwing in complications like these without explaining the basics.

Comment: Alright, such a nice and thoughtful response. Thank you a lot.